# Excel calculation in PHP

Tags: php, google-sheets, calculation

I am working on a table where some of the data is comming back directly from an api and some of it is calculated. I have an google spreadsheets sheet as an example for diffrent values and am having some trouble translating the formulas used to PHP code.

Example of a row in spreadsheets:

| A18 | B18 | C18 | E18 | H18 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5000 | 91 | 9.7 | 72 | 0.7740 |

Note that this is just one example.

- The values I know in my PHP because I get them back from the api are **A18**, **C18** and **E18**
- **H18** is calculated by excel formula `=AFRONDEN(((((1+(C18))^(1/12))-1)*100*1000)/1000,3)` . I managed this in PHP and the value is saved in a variable
- I am trying to calculate B18, where the outcome should be 91 for this example. The formula as it is in google sheets is `=-BET(H18/100,E18,A18)`

I tried to use diffrent ways of calculation but ended up with really weird numbers, Also tried to investigate PMT instead of BET but with no success so far. Does someone know how to approach this?

Comment: Could you please elaborate what -BET() is doing? I don't have this option in the English version of Spreadsheet.

Comment: BET _is_ the Dutch version of PME, according to what I found. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pmt-function-0214da64-9a63-4996-bc20-214433fa6441

Comment: Tould you mean PMT instead of PME ? I did not know this, I will continue my search with this info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see based on PMT, your calculation should be like this in PHP:

```
A18 * H18/100 * pow(1 + H18/100, E18) / (pow(1 + H18/100, E18) - 1)
```

This is not rounded. If you need to, use round().

Side note: If you want to use this for a real application with financial values, please keep in mind that the division operation will result in a float-value, which is not always precise.

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick . If it is not too much of a hassle, can you maybe explain this?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot completely explain it in a mathematical way. I just looked up the formula to calculate the periodic payment (annuity) and converted the formula to a PHP calculation  :-D

Comment: Cool, thank you very much! All the other things I tried gave me really weird long negative numbers and this one works!